# How to invoke a method in a controller from a Html.DropDownListFor onchange?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying invoke code in a controller with an onchange event on my Html.DropDownListFor element but I can't get it to work. Tried multiple versions, even with JavaScript but the main problem is that I cannot trigger the onchange event.

Controller code:

```
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Cat_ID = new SelectList(_context.Category, "Cat_ID", "Cat_Name");

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult CreatePopulateSCat(string CatID)
        {
            ViewBag.SCat_ID = new SelectList(from s in _context.SubCategory where s.Category.Cat_ID == CatID select s).ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

View code:

```
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.Category.Cat_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Cat_ID, new { @class = "form-control" @onchange = "ICantGetYouToWork" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.SCat_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.SCat_ID, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Maybe with jQuery: `$('select').change(function () { //GET of POST data here to the Controller and handle the Response });`

Comment: Where is your `ICantGetYouToWork` method?